# Freeradius translate MSCHAP to PAP and proxy request

Tags: freeradius

i want to authenticate a connection (VPN) agains a RSA Server.
The Source (VPN Client) speaks MSCHAP, but the RSA only understands PAP.

So my idea was to use an Freeradius as Proxy to translate/convert the MSCHAP Request to PAP and ask the RSA Server for Authetication.

But i can't find a way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible. You can’t retrieve the plaintext password from the MSCHAPv2 response as it has undergone multiple hashing rounds by the time it is received by the server.

You can’t retrieve the input text to a hash, the best you can do is generate a collision (input text that produces the same hash output), and that doesn’t help you here due to the time in which you’d need to do it.